# How to restore punctuation using Python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, lstm

I would like to restore commas and full stops in text without punctuation. For example, let's take this sentence:

```
I am XYZ I want to execute I have a doubt
```

And I would like to detect that there should be 1 commas and 1 full stop in the above example:

```
I am XYZ, I want to execute. I have a doubt.
```

Can anyone advise me on how to achieve this using Python and NLP concepts?

Comment: I'd have put full stops in both places to be honest. :P Languages are funny.

Comment: And I'd put either 2 full stops or the comma and a full stop... but the other way around. And theoretically, shouldn't semicolon be used for two "sentences" without a connecting word? Punctuation in English is a very flexible thing, especially with so many non-native speakers using it.

Comment: From my knowledge There is no method of any module which can extract sentences from long collection of words. You need to make your own method which will find out starting prepostions, wh words etc toh find out the start of the sentences. I am working on a ongoing project which has a function of this please look through it. https://github.com/badamakashprasad/project_riya

Comment: Sorry , Actually I wanted the solution in terms of algorithm in python (Coding).

Answer (score 4):

If I understand well, you want to improve the quality of a sentence by adding the appropriate punctuation. This is sometimes called **punctuation restoration**.

A good first step is to apply the usual NLP pipeline, namely [tokenization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization), [POS tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging), and [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree), using libraries such as [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) or [Spacy](https://spacy.io/).

Once this preprocessing is done, you'll have to apply a rule-based or a machine learning approach to define where the punctuation should be, based on the features extracted from the NLP pipeline (e.g. sentence boundaries, parsing tree, POS, etc.).

However this is not a trivial task. It can require strong NLP/AI skills if you want to customise your algorithm.

**Some examples that can be reused:**

- [Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48575/is-there-any-nlp-library-or-package-which-can-help-in-adding-coma-punctuations) is a simple approach using Spacy, mainly based on sentence boundaries.
- [Here](https://github.com/ottokart/punctuator2) is a more complex solution, using the [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/) deep learning library.